# Making AddOrUpdate change only some properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

This might be a simple question, however I'm new to Code First and Migrations so bear with me. I'll keep sample code to a minimum to show the problem:

I have a `BaseAuditableEntity` which includes this (among other things, but let's simplify):

```
public abstract class BaseAuditableEntity : BaseEntity, IAuditableEntity
{
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Now a (for example) `User` POCO inherits from it:

```
public class User : BaseAuditableEntity
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
  public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

I have this on my context's `SaveChanges` method, to fill in the `CreatedOn` and `LastModified` dates (simplified):

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
  var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditableEntity>();

  if (changeSet != null)
  {
    foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(p => p.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
    {
      var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
      if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        entry.Entity.CreatedOn = now;
      entry.Entity.LastModified = now;
    }
  }      
  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

And now I have a migration in place that seeds some users, like this:

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
  context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
      p => p.UserName,
      new User { Active = true, 
                 FullName = "My user name",
                 UserName = "ThisUser",
                 PasswordHash = "",
                 Email = "my@email",
                 LastLogin = null,
            }
      // etc.
    );
}
```

Now I have a problem on seeding with `AddOrUpdate` after the migration. When the entity is new (it's being added), `CreatedOn` gets filled correctly and everything works as expected. However when the entity is modified (it already exists on the database and `UserName` matches), it tries to update it with the new entity I'm creating... this fails because `CreatedOn` has an invalid `DateTime` (in this case, `DateTime.MinValue`).

Is there any way to use the `AddOrUpdate` method so that it actually retrieves the matching entity from the database and just update the non-default fields? Or maybe some way to tell it which fields NOT to update? For this specific case, I'd like the `CreatedOn` field to be unchanged, but a generic solution would be appreciated.

Maybe I should do my own `AddOrUpdate` method which includes a predicate with the fields I want to change, instead of passing it a completely new entity?

This is EF 6.1

## Update

I know I can easily solve this for the `CreatedOn` date, this is what I'm currently doing for this specific case:

```
foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
{
  var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
  if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
  {
    entry.Entity.CreatedOn = now;
  }
  else
  {
    if (entry.Property(p => p.CreatedOn).CurrentValue == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
      var original = entry.Property(p => p.CreatedOn).OriginalValue;
      entry.Property(p => p.CreatedOn).CurrentValue = original != SqlDateTime.MinValue ? original : now;
      entry.Property(p => p.CreatedOn).IsModified = true;
     }
   }
   entry.Entity.LastModified = now;
}
```

I am looking for a more generic solution though

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The implementation of [`AddOrUpdate`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbSetMigrationsExtensions.cs) uses [`CurrentValues.SetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679336%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) so that all scalar properties will be modified.

I have extended the functionality to accept properties to be modified when it's an update, otherwise it's a creation, just use [`DbSet<T>::Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public static class SeedExtension
{
    public static void Upsert<T>(this DbContext db, Expression<Func<T, object>> identifierExpression, Expression<Func<T, object>> updatingExpression, params T[] entities)
        where T : class
    {
        if (updatingExpression == null)
        {
            db.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(identifierExpression, entities);
            return;
        }

        var identifyingProperties = GetProperties<T>(identifierExpression).ToList();
        Debug.Assert(identifyingProperties.Count != 0);

        var updatingProperties = GetProperties<T>(updatingExpression).Where(pi => IsModifiedable(pi.PropertyType)).ToList();
        Debug.Assert(updatingProperties.Count != 0);

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var matches = identifyingProperties.Select(pi => Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name), Expression.Constant(pi.GetValue(entity, null))));
            var matchExpression = matches.Aggregate<BinaryExpression, Expression>(null, (agg, v) => (agg == null) ? v : Expression.AndAlso(agg, v));

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(matchExpression, new[] { parameter });
            var existing = db.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
            if (existing == null)
            {
                // New.
                db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
                continue;
            }

            // Update.
            foreach (var prop in updatingProperties)
            {
                var oldValue = prop.GetValue(existing, null);
                var newValue = prop.GetValue(entity, null);
                if (Equals(oldValue, newValue)) continue;

                db.Entry(existing).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = true;
                prop.SetValue(existing, newValue);                    
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsModifiedable(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsPrimitive || type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> exp) where T : class
    {
        Debug.Assert(exp != null);
        Debug.Assert(exp.Body != null);
        Debug.Assert(exp.Parameters.Count == 1);

        var type = typeof(T);
        var properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        if (exp.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var memExp = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memExp != null && memExp.Member != null)
                properties.Add(type.GetProperty(memExp.Member.Name));
        }
        else if (exp.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            var unaryExp = exp.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExp != null)
            {
                var propExp = unaryExp.Operand as MemberExpression;
                if (propExp != null && propExp.Member != null)
                    properties.Add(type.GetProperty(propExp.Member.Name));
            }
        }
        else if (exp.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.New)
        {
            var newExp = exp.Body as NewExpression;
            if (newExp != null)
                properties.AddRange(newExp.Members.Select(x => type.GetProperty(x.Name)));
        }

        return properties.OfType<PropertyInfo>();
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
context.Upsert(
    p => p.UserName,   
    p => new { p.Active, p.FullName, p.Email },
    new User
    {
        Active = true, 
        FullName = "My user name",
        UserName = "ThisUser",
        Email = "my@email",
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, your `Upsert` method works just fine, and that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I've modified the update so that it checks that properties are not the same value (for primitive/value/string types), so it doesn't mark the entities as 'Modified' if their values are the same and leaves them `Unchanged`. For the purpose of seeding, I believe this is even better.

In the specific case of my question, this makes it not modify `LastModified` all the time

Comment: @Jcl, you're right, that prevents unnecessary update. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: This works great! I ran into the same issue when seeding data during migrations that were overwriting the new DateTimeOffset during object initialization.

Comment: Awesome solution. You saved me!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue with Expression.Equals in @Yuliam's answer where a type was nullable and had to add the following.

```
var matches = identifyingProperties.Select(pi => 
     Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name), 
     Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(pi.GetValue(entity, null)), 
     Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name).Type)));
```

I also updated this to fetch all records first so "SingleOrDefault" doesn't execute a sql query in each for loop iteration.

I also set AddRange which gets a little better performance.

Here is a gist of my solution.  Thanks for posting this Yuliam! I've been looking for something like this for a while.

https://gist.github.com/twilly86/eb6b61a22b66b4b33717aff84a31a060