# EF Core - Obtain new Ids after upsert, then use them to add new entity to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, upsert

I'm trying to use [this function from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162909/3935156) to add an entity to the database if it doesn't exist:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static EntityEntry<T> AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
        return !exists ? dbSet.Add(entity) : null;
    }
}
```

To add a join table entity into the database straight after adding the two single table entities (which will be assigned new Ids upon insertion). I am using [FlexLabs Upsert](https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert) to insert/update depending on if they already exist for the two single table entities:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<GroceryItemGroceryStore>> PostGroceryItemGroceryStore(GroceryItemGroceryStore groceryItemGroceryStore)
{
    
    await _context.GroceryItems.Upsert(groceryItemGroceryStore.VeganItem).On(v => new { v.Name, v.Brand }).RunAsync();
    await _context.GroceryStores.Upsert(groceryItemGroceryStore.Establishment).On(c => c.PlaceId).RunAsync();
    _context.SaveChanges();
    
    _context.Set<GroceryItemGroceryStore>().AddIfNotExists(groceryItemGroceryStore , x => x.VeganItemId == x.VeganItemId && x.EstablishmentId == x.EstablishmentId);
    

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

However, the `x.VeganItemId` and `x.EstablishmentId` are still `0` when trying to add the join entity to the database, as I am not obtaining the new Ids after the first two adds to the database. How do I obtain their newly added Ids from the `Upsert` executions and then use them with `AddIfNotExists` to insert the new Join Entity if one does not exist with a `VeganItemId` of the new `VeganItem.Id` and `EstablishmentId` of the new `Establishment.Id`?

Comment: `dbSet.Add(entity)` should return a insert id