# How to pass `params` of a `Func<T>` List with dynamic return?

Tags: c#

I need to call a method that receive a `list` of `Func<T>`, the problem is that the return of the `Func` is not the same for all the items of the list.

For example:

```
//Having the following method:
public void DoSomething(params Expression<Func<T>> list)
{
   //get the property info to get the name and value
   // PropertyInfo p = (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
   //EDIT: Using the answer to change the T to object I needed to get the property info using this: 
   (((UnaryExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;

}

//and the following object
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get;set; } //LOOK: ITS A LONG PROPERTY
    public string Name { get; set; } // ITS A STRING PROPERTY
}

//I would like to pass these two expressions of DIFFERENT returning types.
Foo f = new Foo();
DoSomething(() => f.Id, () => f.Name); //TWO RETURN TYPES DIFFERENTS.
```

The compiler says that it's impossible because the method param is a `Generic Type` `T`, so all the Funcs passed needs to be the of the same return type.

Comment: I'm using `params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] columns` in my micro ORM to specify multiple columns.

Comment: `Func<T1, T2>` tells the compiler that you the incoming parameters is `T1`, and that the func will return `T2`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @code4life no, the `T2` must be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `params Expression<Func<object>>[] list` as a parameter, instead of `T` (note that it must be an array for using with `params`)

You will, of course, need to cast the result to work with it (unless your process can work with `object`... say to do a `ToString()`, for example) inside `DoSomething`, but how else were you expecting to work with `T` when `T` can be different depending on the parameter?

*Update*: I've made an example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5uIRR6), but what you can do with this is pretty much limited, so as @juharr stated in the comments, it'd be better if you explained what do you want to do so we can suggest more practical alternatives

Also, if you don't need the expression (just the callback), there's no need to pass a expression, just pass the `Func` ([modified fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4KkfAb))

Comment: It happen because when I create my method, it works with only one `Func` but now I'm changing to receive a list of them.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind Maybe if you explain what you method does we can suggest an alternative solution to what you are currently trying.

Comment: Yes, because it sounds quite weird. I've made an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5uIRR6 , but it doesn't look very practical (it compiles and works, but what you can do with such a method is very limited)

Comment: I will told you a little explanation about what I am doing. I'm developing my database access with NHibernate, and this "DoSomething"  is a method where I will update a object to database, so I will pass all the properties that I need to update, get the `PropertyInfo`, get the value of the property, and create the `HQL` dynamically ^^

Comment: Its just a easy way to develop, to don't need create methods like: "UpdateNameById", "UpdateFoo", "UpdateBar".
I will have just this method and pass whats the properties that I would like update

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind I'd rather pass an anonymous object with the properties set to whatever needed, and browse it using reflection. This is for EF, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25931098/68972) to a question of mine, it basically does what you want (pass in an object that defines which properties to update, and then the values in an anonymous object)

Comment: @Jcl its now usefull for us because we don't have a 'default', sometimes my object have all the variables populated, but I would like to update just one of them.

Comment: I think I understand, you are using the expression to get to the property without using reflection, correct ?

Comment: @Jcl So, this is a way to specify whats the property that I want to update, get the name and the value, passing just one parameter to the method

Comment: @user957902 Yes basically it

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind I understand what you want. Check the answer I linked in the above comment: it does exactly that: it passes a expression of `Func<T, object>>` to define the properties, and then the entities with the values... it uses reflection to read the object. Of course, the code is very specific for EF and it's an upsert, which is not what you want, but the "base" for what you want is there. I don't know any NHibernate to do the updating code for you tho.

Comment: @Jcl Of course I will check. I'm just checking first if specifying the return as a `object` instead the generic `T` will work fine

Comment: It should, but again, you won't be able to work with each property directly in a type-safe manner (since the generic type can't be dynamic)... you'd need to either cast it or read the property via reflection (or use `dynamic` and let the runtime swallow it). Since you are building HQL, reflection should do for you I think

Comment: @Jcl Luckly I dont manipulate the property value inside the method, I just set the value as a parameter to the query

Comment: Then it should work just by changing to `object`, generics are there for type-safety (and to a extreme, performance), but if you don't need it, `object` should do :-)

Comment: @Jcl It didn't work, because I need to cast the expression body to a `MemberExpression` to after get the `PropertyInfo` inside it. I've edited my code to show you what I am doing.

Comment: @Jcl I found a way to get the `PropertyInfo` of an `Expression` without a generic type `T`. I put the solution on my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind yeah, I was about to try to write that for you, but my kid came and wouldn't let me the keyboard. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

OK, its not pretty, but I think this is the only way its going to work with generics. It probably not a practical solution:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Expression<Func<T>> p)
{

}

public void DoSomething<T1,T2>(Expression<Func<T1>> p1,Expression<Func<T2>> p2)
{

}

public void DoSomething<T1,T2,T3>(Expression<Func<T1>> p1,Expression<Func<T2>> p2,Expression<Func<T3>> p3)
{

}

//etc...
```

Microsoft does the samae thing with its Func deligates

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4, in T5, in T6, inT7, in T8, in T9, in T10, in T11, in T12, in T13, in T14, out TResult>(
    T1 arg1,
    T2 arg2,
    T3 arg3,
    T4 arg4,
    T5 arg5,
    T6 arg6,
    T7 arg7,
    T8 arg8,
    T9 arg9,
    T10 arg10,
    T11 arg11,
    T12 arg12,
    T13 arg13,
    T14 arg14
)
```

Comment: Yeah, it works but is a very bad solution haha I give an upvote to you because it works.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a fluent interface instead of a list

```
public object Command
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
       //do something, act on values stored in member var;
    }

    public Command AddProp<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propAndValue)
    {
       // Get property and value from expression
       // store in member var
       return this;
    }
}



public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get;set; } //LOOK: ITS A LONG PROPERTY
    public string Name { get; set; } // ITS A STRING PROPERTY
}

// Example usage

Foo f = new Foo();
Command cmd = new Command();

cmd.AddProp(() => f.Id).AddProp(() => f.Name).DoSomething();
```

Comment: Hahaha I already do, something like this. The point is that I would like to pass directly the parameter Func list..